# OpenLDAP Installation - Build Configure for LDIF

Tags: linux, openldap, ldif

I want to build openldap on linux, aix, and sun solaris. I require openldap only for use in regression tests on these machines.  For this purpose I only need ldif. I want to avoid any potential licensing problems and expenses related to Oracle Berkeley DB.

I have downloaded by FTP the tar file openldap-2.4.40.tgz to a linux machine. I then ran,
    tar -zxvf openldap-2.4.40.tgz
    cd openldap-2.4.40

To configure the source ready for the build,
    ./configure --enable-ldif=yes

The log ended in;

```
...
checking for gethostbyaddr_r... yes
checking number of arguments of ctime_r... 2
checking number of arguments of gethostbyname_r... 6
checking number of arguments of gethostbyaddr_r... 8
checking db.h usability... no
checking db.h presence... no
checking for db.h... no
configure: error: BDB/HDB: BerkeleyDB not available
```

Can I get OpenLDAP built for only LDIF, or at least not depended on Oracle Berkeley DB? How?

Comment: ./configure --enable-bdb=no --enable-hdb=no

Comment: No option --enable-ldif

Comment: Then "make depend" and "make install"

Comment: ./configure --prefix=<BASE-DIR> --enable-bdb=no --enable-hdb=no

Answer (score 0):

There is no enable-ldif option anymore. You get LDIF format by default.
To disable BerkeleyDB

```
./configure --enable-bdb=no --enable-hdb=no
make depend
make install
```

For my purposes I found the --prefix option useful.

So far I have been able to build it on Linux, Solaris, and AIX.

But on AIX could only build static libraries. But that is another question.